# How to build this project into a single Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently working on integrating a chat system into my web application. This is the project which is given to me to take as a base: https://github.com/smilefam/SendBird-JavaScript/tree/master/web-widget

I have made some changes to the JS and SCSS files. Now how do I build it into the single Javascript file so that I can import it to my application?

I am executing the following command

```
npm run build
```

But it throws an error saying,

```
npm ERR! missing script: build
```

I am a complete newbie to Node and hence looking for some help.

Comment: `npm run blah` looks for a command in `package.json`'s `script` section. If you look there you only have `start-dev`, `start` and `test`. You probably need either `npm run start-dev` or `npm run start`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The build was successful with npm run start

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in your [package.json](https://github.com/smilefam/SendBird-JavaScript/blob/master/web-widget/package.json) I understand that you have not defined a `build` command under the `scripts` section.

Adding a `build` command there should work.

Answer (score 0):

This error appears because you don't have a `build` script inside of the scripts field in your `package.json`.
Your scripts should be defined in your `package.json`.

To read more information about how to make a `package.json`, click on [here](http://nodesource.com/blog/the-basics-of-package-json-in-node-js-and-npm/)

Hope this helps.